# Add a plane to a tikzpicture and make it appear more three dimensional

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

Please consider the following configuration of vectors.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$\varepsilon_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[anchor=north west]{$\varepsilon_2$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=south east]{$\tilde{\beta}_3=\varepsilon_3$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (3,-3,0) node[anchor=east]{$\tilde{\beta}_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,-3) node[anchor=north west]{$\tilde{\beta}_2$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,-3,-3) node[anchor=east]{$\beta_2$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,2,1) node[anchor=north west]{$\beta_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

- I want to add the plane spanned by `\beta_1` and `\beta_2` and label it with a math variable.
- I would like to make the picture appear more three dimensional, e.g. by shaded color of the plane or by dashed lines depending on wether something is in front of or behind the plane.
- I don't want the boundary of the plane be drawn but just the inside in color. This command does not work `\filldraw[fill=blue!20] (0,-3,-3) -- (1,-1,-2) -- (1,2,1) --- (0,0,0);` but it gives an error.

I am currently experimenting with `tikz`. It might not be possible to make this specific configuration "good looking". The question is therefore not very specific.

I thank you for your help!

[This is the closest I found on the site and uses some of the tricks I want to implement, cf. the last answer by the OP itself.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286135/3d-graph-with-tikz-or-pgf)

How far I got...

[image: How far I got...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) coordinate(O) -- (0,-3,-3) coordinate(b2) node[anchor=east]{$\beta_2$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (1,2,1) coordinate(b1) node[anchor=north west]{$\beta_1$};
\fill[gray,opacity=0.3,name path=plane] (O) -- (b1) -- ++ (b2) 
node[midway,above,sloped,black,opacity=1]{plane} -- (b2) -- cycle;
\path[name path=E1] (O) -- (3,0,0);
\draw[name intersections={of=plane and E1,by={aux,i1}},dashed] (O)--(i1);
\draw[thick,->] (i1) -- (3,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$\varepsilon_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,3,0) node[anchor=north west]{$\varepsilon_2$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=south east]{$\tilde{\beta}_3=\varepsilon_3$};
\path[name path=B1] (O) -- (3,-3,0);
\draw[name intersections={of=plane and B1,by={aux,i2}},dashed] (O) -- (i2);
\draw[thick,->] (i2) -- (3,-3,0)  node[anchor=east]{$\tilde{\beta}_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,3,-3) node[anchor=north west]{$\tilde{\beta}_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Your command `\filldraw[fill=blue!20] (0,-3,-3) -- (1,-1,-2) -- (1,2,1) --- (0,0,0);` would not throw an error if you were to use 2 `-` in the last segment instead of 3.

Comment: Note, however, things can be made simpler and more compelling with the `tikz-3dplot` package and the `3d` library.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution works fine for me!

Comment: @marmot Ulrike correctly pointed out in the chat that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847) is still the best way of drawing a plane in Tikz.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, seems like you're not a frequent flyer. ;-)